# JSON get Array without object

Tags: java, android, json

I'm trying to parse [this JSON](http://pastebin.com/p5uXwuMX),

```
{
  "listname": "red",
  "lists": [
    {
      "id": "01",
      "name": "paw",
      "list": [
        {
          "id": "A",
          "name": "pawa",
          "bar": "foo"
        },
        {
          "id": "B",
          "name": "pawb",
          "bar": "foo"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "id": "02",
      "name": "pew",
      "list": [
        {
          "id": "A",
          "name": "pewa",
          "bar": "foo"
        },
        {
          "id": "B",
          "name": "pewb",
          "bar": "foo"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "id": "03",
      "name": "piw",
      "list": [
        {
          "id": "A",
          "name": "piwa",
          "bar": "foo"
        },
        {
          "id": "B",
          "name": "piwb",
          "bar": "foo"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

I put it on `Asset Folder` and I read it and it converts it to me to `String` since here all good, the problem is when I'm trying to get the `name` from each item of `lists` and trying to get all the names from the `list` I've tried it doing this :

```
JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(str);
JSONArray jsonMainArr = obj.getJSONArray("lists"); //first get the lists
for (int i = 0; i < jsonMainArr.length(); i++) { 
   JSONObject childJSONObject = jsonMainArr.getJSONObject(i);
   String name = childJSONObject.getString("name");
   Toast.makeText(context, name, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}

JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(str);
JSONArray jsonMainArr = obj.getJSONArray("list"); //get the list
for (int i = 0; i < jsonMainArr.length(); i++) { 
   JSONObject childJSONObject = jsonMainArr.getJSONObject(i);
   String name = childJSONObject.getString("name");
   Toast.makeText(context, name, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

But it doesn't show anything... what I'm missing?

### EDIT

This is how I read the `JSON`

```
 public static String loadJSONFromAsset(Context ctx, String str) {
    String json = null;
    try {

        InputStream is = ctx.getAssets().open(str);

        int size = is.available();
        byte[] buffer = new byte[size];
        is.read(buffer);
        is.close();
        json = new String(buffer, "UTF-8");

    } catch (IOException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }
    return json;

}
```

Comment: I tried this in plain **Java** & it worked as expected. Check if there was something wrong with the `context`.

Comment: just debug it ...and check whether that array json has elements or not

Comment: Hello @MohammedAoufZOUAG :), I did it with `Log` and doesn't work either

Comment: @Skizo make sure that the execution flow reaches this code block & **double** check if `str` is actually populated with data. As I said, your code's logic is correct (I used **sysout**s instead of **toast**s & it worked), the problem is something else :)

Comment: @MohammedAoufZOUAG str is populated because I create a Toast and it shows all the JSON, so....

Comment: @Skizo can you share more **relevant** code to this matter ?

Comment: @MohammedAoufZOUAG Sure, I'll post the reader, hold on.

Comment: @MohammedAoufZOUAG Done :)

Comment: @Skizo same thing, JSON successfully read, same output. There is something else going on...

Comment: It says : `org.json.JSONException: No value for lists`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since your "list" is nested in the `childJSONObject` (from "lists") , nest your for loops to retrieve the this set of values (the JSONobject)

```
JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(str);
//first get the top-level "lists"
JSONArray jsonMainArr = obj.getJSONArray("lists");
for (int i = 0; i < jsonMainArr.length(); i++) { 
   JSONObject childJSONObject = jsonMainArr.getJSONObject(i);
   String name = childJSONObject.getString("name");
   Toast.makeText(context, name, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
   //get the inner "list" from childJSONObject
   JSONArray childJSONArray = childJSONObject.getJSONArray("list"); 
   for (int j = 0; j < childJSONArray.length(); j++) {
      JSONObject childJSONObjectB = childJSONArray.getJSONObject(j);
      String name = childJSONObjectB.getString("name");
      Toast.makeText(context, name, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
   }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but saddly it doesn't work, it still without showing nothing on my Toast...

Comment: Says `org.json.JSONException: No value for lists`

Comment: Dont know,  Try logging the `str` from the first line. Its possible that it is empty?

Comment: Nope I show a Toast that shows the full JSON, well I'm gonna debug it again

Comment: can you explain me the reason why if I put other name on `getJSONArray("list");` it doesn't work? seems like it only reads the first array and the rest does not...

Comment: @Skizo  yea, shortversion:  your `list` is nested within `lists`.  Long : your JSON has a `lists` attribute & value that is a JSON Array. It does not have any `list` attrs/values.  However,  that JSON Array (`lists`) has a bunch of items that each have a `list` attr/value (which is also a JSON Array ). So using nested for loops this way, allows you to iterate and locate your data/`list` correctly given the structure of your JSON